# Determine if expression is true for all array elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of objects in Ruby. I'd like to pass each one to an expression/block and see whether the block evaluates to true. The result I'm interested in is the case where the block is true for all array elements.

Right now I've coded this with a counter. I use .each on the array, evaluate the expression, and increment the counter if the expression is true, then check the counter vs the array size at the end.

It makes me tired even to describe it :) This feels very clunky, so I'm hoping there is a more concise Ruby idiom for this.

Comment: Notice the symetry between `a.all? { |e| f(e) }` and `a.any? { |e| !f(e) }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

```
[1, 2, 3].all? { |x| x > 1 }
# => false
[1, 2, 3].all? { |x| x >= 1 }
# => true
```

Comment: Beautiful. Knew it had to be in there.

Comment: @SteveLane Read through the various methods in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html) because there is a very rich tool-chest there.